# How do I allow placeholders to be empty in SQLite3 in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a "Sales Order" database right now and I am supposed to implement a search function that allows the user to enter in data like, customer first name, last name, order ID, customer ID, etc. The problem I am having is that the customer does not have to enter anything for the fields and instead just press enter to leave it blank to skip. But SQL seems to be taking that as an empty input and looking for an empty field. How can I make it so that the program instead allows anything to be accepted by the placeholder rather than looking for a blank. Thanks!

```
initialSearchInformation = [input("Enter Customer Last Name (To skip, press ENTER)"),
                            input("Enter Customer Email (To skip, press ENTER)"),
                            input("Enter Customer Number (To skip, press ENTER)"),
                            input("Enter Order Number (To skip, press ENTER)"),
                            input("Enter Order Amount Greater Than (To skip, press ENTER)"),
                            input("Enter Order Amount Less Than (To skip, press ENTER)")]

    conn = create_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT * 
                   FROM SalesOrder 
                       INNER JOIN Customer 
                       ON Customer.CustomerID = SalesOrder.CustomerID 
                   WHERE SalesOrderID=? 
                       AND SalesOrder.CustomerID=? 
                       AND Amount > ? 
                       AND Amount < ? 
                       AND Customer.CustomerName LIKE ?""", (initialSearchInformation[3], initialSearchInformation[2], initialSearchInformation[4], initialSearchInformation[5], '%'+initialSearchInformation[0]+'%',))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print("\nInfo Found: ")
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for an empty value in your SQL. E.g. replace

```
SalesOrderId = ?
```

with

```
(? = '' OR SalesOrderID = ?)
```

Since there are now two placeholders, you'll need to duplicate the corresponding element in the parameter tuple:

```
initialSearchInformation[3], initialSearchInformation[3]
```

The full query becomes

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * 
    FROM SalesOrder 
    INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = SalesOrder.CustomerID 
    WHERE (? = '' OR SalesOrderID=?) 
        AND (? = '' OR SalesOrder.CustomerID=?) 
        AND (? = '' OR Amount > ?) 
        AND (? = '' OR Amount < ?) 
        AND (? = '' OR Customer.CustomerName LIKE ?)""", 
    (initialSearchInformation[3], initialSearchInformation[3], 
     initialSearchInformation[2], initialSearchInformation[2], 
     initialSearchInformation[4], initialSearchInformation[4], 
     initialSearchInformation[5], initialSearchInformation[5], 
     initialSearchInformation[0], '%'+initialSearchInformation[0]+'%',))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Im very new to SQL and SQLite3 so this was definitely a big insight for me, thanks!